# Is there any available 3d SLAM except rgbdslam package?

Tags: slam, navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to build 3D point cloud in the room.

Because my computer is slow(CPU always 100% and seems work very slow) when running rgbdslam package, I want to try another available package or improve rgbdslam.

What should I do?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43012/is-there-any-available-3d-slam-except-rgbdslam-package?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-09-04

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sudhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1685/sudhan/) on 2012-09-04**:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/ethzasl_ptam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Multiresolution Surfel Map package performs RGB-D-SLAM in real time on a CPU:
see code.google.com/p/mrsmap

---

Originally posted by [Sven Behnke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4059/sven-behnke/) with karma: 43 on 2013-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) on 2013-01-26**:
Is there a ROS wrapper? Did you get it to work in conjunction with the ROS RGBD-SLAM?

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2013-02-06**:
This SLAM needs PCL1.7. How you download PCL1.7? I only can get PCL1.6 from PCL webpage.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ptam from the ETH stack is may an option for you

---

Originally posted by [tlinder](https://answers.ros.org/users/2680/tlinder/) with karma: 663 on 2012-09-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-09-05**:
Is this package suitable for indoor 3D point cloud SLAM? It seems be using in outdoors. Thank you~

**Comment by [tlinder](https://answers.ros.org/users/2680/tlinder/) on 2012-09-06**:
PTAM can work for both, indoor and outdoor.

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-09-06**:
Is this package suitable for dynamic environment objects changing? Thank you~